Quicksort segmentation fault
I implemented a quicksort algorithm in C and works properly in vectors with less that 30000 elements. But, it's get a segmentation fault
in line
swap(&vet[sup], &vet[(sup-inf+1)/2]);

with bigger vectors.
This is the full algorithm:
void swap(int* a, int* b){
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
} 
int partition(int inf, int sup, int vet[]){
    while (inf<sup){
        while (vet[inf]<=vet[sup] && inf<sup){inf++;}
        while (vet[inf]<=vet[sup] && inf<sup){sup--;}
        if (inf<sup){swap(&vet[inf], &vet[sup]);}
    }
    return inf;
}
void median (int inf, int sup, int vet[]){ //select the median of the first, last and midle value of the vector
    if (vet[inf]>vet[(sup-inf+1)/2])
        swap(&vet[inf], &vet[(sup-inf+1/2)]);
    if (vet[sup]>vet[(sup-inf+1)/2])
        swap(&vet[sup], &vet[(sup-inf+1)/2]);  
    else if (vet[sup]<vet[inf])
        swap(&vet[sup], &vet[inf]);    
}
void quicksort(int inf, int sup, int vet[]){
    if (inf<sup){
        median(inf, sup, vet);    
        int piv=partition(inf, sup, vet);
        quicksort(inf, piv-1, vet);
        quicksort(piv+1, sup, vet);
    }
}

I'm tried to write the quicksort which the minimal declaration of variables as possible, but it still getting a segmentation fault. I'm don't know if it's a stack overflow or is a problem with the pointer that only happens with bigger vectors.
Sorry for my bad English, I'm still learning

What does the debugger tell you? Is sup out of bounds? How did it get out of bounds? Is vet invalid? How did it become invalid? Is sup/2+1 out of bounds? How did it get out of bounds? (I would keep my eye on sup/2+1.)

Please explain to your nearest rubber duck why you need sup/2+1.

With a vector of 50000 elements, it's get a segmentation fault with sup=9996. The sup/2+1 is the middle element of the vector, it's necessary because the pivot is the median of the first, last and middle element.

"The sup/2+1 is the middle element of the vector" Really? Of which vector? Please be very explicit about that.

The resut vector of each recall of quicksort

So you call quicksort with inf=10000 and sup=10020. Of which vector sup/2+1 is the middle?

Explain further what median does exactly. It is written in the comment that it "selects the median of the first, last and midle value".  What does it do with the selected value? How does it influence subsequent operations?

By the way if inf==sup, then (inf+sup)/2+1 is in the middle of what?

The median works by choose the median element and swap with the last. The partition works by choose the last element as the pivot. The inf==sup will never occur because of the if (inf<sup) in the start of the quicksort

"The partition works by choose the last element as the pivot" Have you actually tested that? Add printf ("Pivot index %d between %d and %d\n", piv, inf, sup);, run and see what happens.

I already done this before, and yes, it's work propely. Te code works perfectly with vectors with 30000 or less elements. The problem is the larger vectors

There are multiple problems in your code:

your coding style is hard to read and debug: for example cramming the test and the swapping code on the same line makes it impossible to tell which part causes the crash. Write a single statement per line and break control statements on multiple lines.

the swapping code xor trick is obsolete: it is cryptic, potentially undefined and inefficient, Worse even: it does not work if a and b point to the same location. Use the simpler code:
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}


the partition code is incorrect: you must save the initial value of sup so all comparisons are performed with the pivot value and you must swap the pivot to the final inf index:
int partition(int inf, int sup, int vet[]) {
    int pivot = sup;
    while (inf < sup) {
        while (vet[inf] <= vet[pivot] && inf < sup) {
            inf++;
        }
        while (vet[sup] >= vet[pivot] && inf < sup) {
            sup--;
        }
        swap(&vet[inf], &vet[sup]);
    }
    swap(&vet[inf], &vet[pivot]);
    return inf;
}


it is possible, although unlikely that the dataset provided to your code be crafted to cause a stack overflow.  You might want to study the classic article by Doug McIlroy: A killer adversary to QuickSort that explains how to construct such a vector.  A simple counter measure that prevents potential stack overflow but does not reduce the quadratic time complexity is easy to implement: only recurse on the smaller half and loop on the larger half.

a more likely the reason for the crash is you do not select the middle element in the slice with sup/2+1, you should write (inf + (sup - inf + 1) / 2, hence the pivot is not correctly selected so the algorithm may recurse too many times even for a random vector.


Here is a modified version:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int partition(int inf, int sup, int vet[]) {
    int pivot = sup;
    while (inf < sup) {
        while (vet[inf] <= vet[pivot] && inf < sup) {
            inf++;
        }
        while (vet[sup] >= vet[pivot] && inf < sup) {
            sup--;
        }
        swap(&vet[inf], &vet[sup]);
    }
    swap(&vet[inf], &vet[pivot]);
    return inf;
}

// Select the median of the first, last and middle value of the vector
// and move it to vet[sup]
void median(int inf, int sup, int vet[]) {
    int m = inf + (sup - inf + 1) / 2;
    // set vet[m] = min(vet[inf], vet[m])
    if (vet[inf] > vet[m]) {
        swap(&vet[inf], &vet[m]);
    }
    if (vet[sup] > vet[m]) {
        // set vet[sup] = min(vet[sup], min(vet[m], vet[inf]))
        swap(&vet[sup], &vet[m]);
    } else
    if (vet[sup] < vet[inf]) {
        // set vet[sup] = min(vet[sup], max(vet[m], vet[inf]))
        swap(&vet[sup], &vet[inf]);
    }    
}

void quicksort(int inf, int sup, int vet[]) {
    while (inf < sup) {
        median(inf, sup, vet);    
        int piv = partition(inf, sup, vet);
        // recurse on the smaller half, loop on the other half
        if (piv - inf < sup - piv) {
            quicksort(inf, piv - 1, vet);
            inf = piv + 1;
        } else {
            quicksort(piv + 1, sup, vet);
            sup = piv - 1;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    size_t n = argc < 2 ? 30000 : strtol(argv[1], NULL, 0);
    int *array = calloc(n, sizeof(*array));
    int res = 0;

    if (array == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot allocate memory for %zu elements\n", n);
        return 1;
    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array[i] = rand();
    }

    quicksort(0, n - 1, array);
    for (size_t i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (array[i] < array[i - 1]) {
            printf("sort error at %zu: %d > %d\n",
                   i, array[i - 1], array[i]);
            res = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    free(array);
    return res;
}


Thanks for the response, I appreciate it. But I could not test it because it's too expensive to test. With 30000 elements, it run over a minute and not even finished, the old algorithm do it with 2.5 seconds

But I edit the code to facilitate reading

@Thallysson: sorry, I had a bug: sup = piv; was supposed to be sup = piv - 1; and I missed another bug in your partition function causing massive inefficiencies. I amended the answer with a simple benchmark using a random array.  This version sorts 100 million random integers in 1.4 seconds on my M2 laptop.
